# Leaflet only renders tiles with 0 y coordinate for game map

Tags: leaflet

I have just started out with Leaflet, and I wanted to make a map for a game I play (GTA V)

I have all the necessary tiles for building a map. However, when I run my code, only 2 tiles show up, that have 0 as their y coordinate.

**My code:**

Javascript:

```js
const map = L.map('map', {}).setView([0.0, 0.0], 0);

const tile = L.tileLayer('tiles/minimap_sea_{y}_{x}.png', {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 2,
    tileSize: 1024,
    bounds: [[0, 0],[3072, 2048]],
    maxNativeZoom: 0,
    minNativeZoom: 0,
    noWrap: true
}).addTo(map);
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512- xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="./script.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
        <title>Test Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #888888;
}
```

Tile picture names:

```
minimap_sea_0_0.png
minimap_sea_0_1.png
minimap_sea_1_0.png
minimap_sea_1_1.png
minimap_sea_2_0.png
minimap_sea_2_1.png
```

I have already tried setting the bounds but that did not work either.

**Solution:**
I specified the coordinate system to be simple at map creation, and negated the y length of my bounds.
New code:
Javascript:

```js
const map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0.0, 0.0], 0);

const tile = L.tileLayer('tiles/minimap_sea_{y}_{x}.png', {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 2,
    tileSize: 1024,
    bounds: [[0, 0],[-3072, 2048]],
    maxNativeZoom: 0,
    minNativeZoom: 0,
    tms: true
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a map not covering a ~sphere (like the Earth), make sure to specify [`L.CRS.Simple`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#crs-l-crs-simple) in the map [`crs` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-crs):

> A simple CRS that maps longitude and latitude into `x` and `y` directly. May be used for maps of flat surfaces (e.g. game maps).

```js
const map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0.0, 0.0], 0);
```

Otherwise at zoom 0, max and min latitudes of default EPSG3857 CRS will clamp to 256px height, 512px at zoom 1, and 1024px at zoom 2, therefore still within your y = 0 tile (1024px size).

See also the Leaflet tutorial covering this case: [Non-geographical maps](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html)

Comment: I have added the simple CRS to my map, and now leaflet tries to fetch tiles with negative y coordinates. The y coordinate never goes above zero. I have tried setting tms, but that did nothing. Edit.: I have just figured it out, I needed to negate the y length of my bounds

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to leaflet confusing the zoom with the y value.  I recommend following the standard slippymap tile structure.  The tiles need to be in a directory structure that follows a zoom/x/y pattern.  It looks like you only have one zoom layer (as far as I can tell).  Lets say its zoom level 0.  Your tiles should be organized like this:

```
/myproj
  myjavascriptfile.js
  /tiles
    /0
      /0
         0.png
         1.png
      /1
         0.png
         1.png
      /2
         0.png
         1.png
```

Now you can tell the tilelayer where to find these like this:

```js
const tile = L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.png')
```

I highly recommend checking out [this article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) on naming map tiles.